# How can I avoid this unnecessary cast in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, syntax

Given there is something along this lines:

```
class Foo {}
class Bar extends Foo {} 
class Baz extends Foo {}
```

I find myself writing this type of code:

```
if (foo is Bar) {
   (foo as Bar).doSomething();    //Compiler warning of unnecessary cast.
} else (foo is Baz) {
   (foo as Bar).doSomething();    //Compiler warning of unnecessary cast.
}
```

I don't know how to avoid this situation.

If I remove the check types of of **is Bar** or **is Baz** before the cast I may get a runtime error and if I don't cast, it means no access to the public stuff on that type.

Maybe I follow a flawed code design that I need to update because I believe I should avoid checking class type.

Is there any method in Dart that may help here?

`(foo as? Bar)?.doSomething()` (swift like)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually you can just do `foo.doSomething();` instead of `(foo as Bar).doSomething()`. The compiler knows that if the condition `if(foo is Bar)` turns out to be true, the variable `foo` in that block of code is of type `Bar`.

Try:

```
if (foo is Bar) {
   foo.doSomething();    // It's automatically inferred that type of `foo` is `Bar`
} else if (foo is Baz) {
   foo.doSomething();    // It's automatically inferred that type of `foo` is `Baz`
}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

With objects oriented languages this kind of if/else or switch statements based on class are solved using polymorphism. If doSomething() is in clase Foo the compiler knows that no matter run time type the method is defined on any child of Foo.

Then if you know that foo is Foo, Bar or Baz you actually should only use foo.doSomething(), no type check and no cast.

The only thing that you need to be aware is to validate that foo is Foo, make sure to use type and not var or dynamic:

```
void doSomething(dynamic foo){
    if (foo is Foo) {
       foo.doSomething(); //Ok with Foo Bar or baz
    }
    foo.doSomething(); //Possible runtime error since foo can be anything
}
```

Since dart is typed is a good practice to use types and not dynamic and you can write directly something like:

```
void doSomething(Foo foo){ //Making sure that you will work with a Foo
       foo.doSomething(); //Ok with Foo Bar or baz with no check
}
```